# FN buttons on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: brightness, volume-control, function-keys, functions

I have installed Ubuntu 17.04 on Acer v3-571G and I want to bring back my FN function buttons functionality like Volume Up and Volume Down, also Brightness controlling functions.
I have tried so more codes from terminal which are I got from askubuntu and there is nothing any changes